# Android Development using c#

Tags: c#, android

Is there a free way to develop apps for my Galaxy Tab (Androind 2.2) using c#? Or are there only paid solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just develop in Java with Eclipse.  It's easy to learn, free do download and use (especially if you already know how to develop in C# with M$ tooling), and there's lots of community support.

Comment: Agreed, C# is pretty much the same thing as java. Maybe starting to differentiate a little bit with the last release, but Java is like writing dumbed down C#

Comment: Sounds like a plan. Is there an IDE I can download? Kinda, a 'Visual Studio 2010' for Eclipse?

Comment: Eclipse is the IDE platform.  The Android dev guide does a decent job of walking through all the steps to get started.  http://developer.android.com

Comment: This answer has to be put as a comment. This is definitely not the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Currently MonoDroid is the only CLR implementation on *Droid platforms so short answer is no. The cheapest solution would be get the student edition from MonoDroid store.

Edit: There is one open source implementation here but the reliability is doubtful: https://github.com/koush/androidmono